# Fuzzy merge in pandas and closest row match

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have two data frames. Each contains 1 word per row. They are pretty close, but there are misspellings and sometimes one df has one or two words the other doesn't.

As a rule, I want to combine df2.word with df1.metadata. If df2.word and df1.word match, are close in spelling, or are close enough and within 1 row from each other, I want to join df2.word with df1.metadata. If there is no close match directly or within 1 row, I want to drop this row.

I have:

```html
df1

word      metadata    metadata2

okay        1           A
I           1           A
win         1           A
tree        1           A
apples      1           A
also        0           B
would       0           B
like        0           B
for         0           B 
oranges     0           B

df2

word

OK.         
I          
want        
three       
apples.     
Also,        
I           
would       
like          
four        
oranges.    


What I want is:

word      metadata    metadata2

OK.         1           B
I           1           B
want        1           B
three       1           B
apples.     1           B
Also,       0           B       
would       0           B
like        0           B
four        0           B
oranges.    0           B
```

Comment: What does “close enough” mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because fuzzy matching is an expensive process, especially as it scales with the amount of data you have, I believe you should leverage concurrency for this.  Also, I believe this is extremely difficult to get 100% accurate, so really you have to settle for assumptions:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor


def get_match(word):
    match, score, _ = process.extractOne(word, df1['word'])
    if score > 50:
        s = df1.loc[df1['word'].eq(match), 'metadata'].iloc[0]
        return [word, s]

def main():
    ##swap out ThreadPoolExecutor with ProcessPoolExecutor to switch from
    ##multithreading to multiprocessing
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(get_match, df2['word'])
        return (r for r in results if r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(main(), columns=['word', 'metadata'])
    print(df)

        word  metadata
0        OK.         1
1          I         1
2       want         1
3      three         1
4    apples.         1
5      Also,         0
6          I         1
7      would         0
8       like         0
9       four         0
10  oranges.         0
```

Comment: thanks this is brilliant! How would I edit this code so that I could work with multiple 'metadata' columns. See edit.

Comment: Should metadata have all 'B'?  If that's a typo, then you can change the `get_match()` function to: `s = df1.loc[df1['word'].eq(match), ['metadata', 'metadata2']].iloc[0]`, then add 'metadata2' to the columns list in the `if __name__=='__main__'` block.